# Is it considered plagiarism to not place quotation marks following a copied sentence if there are footnotes to indicate the source?

Tags: plagiarism

How is this considered plagiarism to do so without the quotation marks? No one is stealing work from a particular author. It is being cited and attributed to him.

Comment: If  you are paraphrasing an author, you don't use quotation marks. If you use the author's actual words you must use quotation marks to distinguish what words are the author's and what are yours.

Comment: Yes, it is plagiarism. Citation without quotation marks tells a reader that you are in debt for your sentence to the cited source in some way, but not for exact wording. If you are in fact in debt to that source for exact wording, that is a lie, and you are passing off someone else's work (in devising that wording) as your own--the very definition of plagiarism.

Comment: This is not a question on the nuts and bolts of the English language, but about how to represent a quotation.

Comment: How can it be plagiarism if there is a footnote? It may not be proper form, but it isn't plagiarism.

Comment: In mathematics, definitions and theorems are often copied verbatim, and they are almost never enclosed in quotation marks. (Of course, the source needs to be referenced.)

Comment: Other edge cases exist: In a fiction, one character may be given to quoting without attribution. Footnoting in such a case may be wholly inappropriate, and other forms of attribution (e.g., another character pointing out the theft) may be partial. Once the character is established as plagiaristic, speech from that character, both before and after the establishment, is suspect. But I suppose I shouldn't muddy the waters by violating the assumption that everybody reading these questions and answers is doing the same thing for the same reasons.

Comment: How long is the citation? For the shorter, emphasis might suffice (italics in roman text)

Comment: Quotations are not about a lack of attribution.  They're about misattribution.  They are about editing.  Quotes are a promise that this hasn't been edited.  This is exactly what was said.  If you say what I said a different way then I said and put it in quotes as if that's what I said you're not guilty of plagiarism.  You're guilty of misquoting.  This is why reporters carry around voice recorders.

Comment: it may not be plagiarism but please, you should be clear whether it is your words or not your words by placing quotation marks...it matters if it is your words then your words could be wrong!

Comment: @BrianDonovan Could you *please* repost your comment as an answer? It much better expresses the relevant well-established norm of the scholarly world, than what is in the current answers. I fear that, if this page remains as it is now, it will put quite a few confused undergraduates, who happen to come across it, on the wrong path.

Answer (score 4):

You have confused a dictate (Do not take credit for the work of others.) with the mechanism of attribution.  You must take extreme care to follow the rule because many institutions for whom you may write regard plagiarism as a strict-liability offense, i.e., intent to deceive is not an element of the offense.

Quotation marks are not always necessary, but if there's even a small likelihood that someone will mistake someone else's words for your own, then you must take steps to insure that the reader will understand whose words are whose.  The style that governs how to do with will be found in your manual of style, either the one you have chosen or the one thrust upon you.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which advises that you use the following alternatives for quotation marks:

- Paragraphing for block quotations.  For longer quotations use indentation and line spacing to set off your words from others'.  The specifications vary with the length of quote and the type of material, and the quote may be introduced with a colon -- "As Karl Marx was wont to opine:"
- Display type.  This is used for introductory  quotes:

> *Against stupidity the gods themselves contend in vain.*
>           --Friedrich Schiller

- No indication. Well-known phrases need not be highlighted or noted.  Here's the example that *CMOS* uses:

> If reading maketh a full man, Henry is half empty.

In this case, *reading maketh a full man* is actually a quote from the essay "Of Studies" by Francis Bacon, but no one will assume the quoter is using his own words.  Notice that I have attributed the example to my reference source so you wouldn't think I'd come up with the example myself.

Because I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If it is copied word-for-word, then put it in quotes and indicate beforehand that it's coming from a certain source (e.g. [Name of source] says, ...). Furthermore, put a citation at the end of the the excerpt.

If it is paraphrased, also introduce the information as having come from a certain source, and then put a citation at the end of the paraphrased section (but quotes are not needed.)

Source: School experience...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not plagiarism per se, but poor writing certainly, as how is the reader to know where the attributed quote begins or ends? You should always use quotation marks or an indented text block or some other means to highlight and call out the other author's work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question straddles two separate concerns, style, and ethics. Stylistically speaking, you should follow an accepted style standard for any formal writing you do (MLA, Chicago Manual of Style, etc.). As for whether the omission of quotes is unethical (or even illegal), I don't think you can can say one way or another, without a specific case providing more context.